# Mongo Query for Booking Between

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

mongodb db Booking schema

Having the bike id,
how to check if new booking is between the booked dates ie: bookingStart and bookingEnd. Here is a sample of the document:

[image: Booking data]

Comment: do you want to check new booking is in between bookingStart and bookingEnd using createdOn field from your schema?

Comment: yes i want to check bike id is booked in between the given dates but not on the created On

Comment: {$and:[{bookingStart:{$lte:'newbookingStart'}},{bookingEnd:{$gte:newbookingEnd}},{bike:{$eq:bikeId}}]}          Will this work

Comment: check my solution hope it will help i have given both the scenarios

Comment: You don't need to apply $and by default find works with $and itself $and is required when you are checking two different condition on same field

Comment: please upvote if you find it useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like below

If you are using mongoose then in your model file define a function and write code like below

```
 var customDate = "28/06/2020"
    Booking.find({
           'bike':'5ef31807335f5541209e4546'
           'bookingStart': {$gte: newDate(customDate) },
           'bookingEnd':{$lte: newDate(customDate)}
      },(err,resdata)=>{
           
      })
```

If you are not using mongoose then you can simply run the following query

```
db.bookings.find({'bike':'5ef31807335f5541209e4546'
           'bookingStart': {$gte: newDate('28/06/2020') },
           'bookingEnd':{$lte: newDate('28/06/2020')}})
```

Comment: Booking.find(
      {$and:[{bookingStart:{$lte:req.cookies['bookingStart']}},{bookingEnd:{$gte:req.cookies['bookingEnd']}},{bike:{$eq:bikeId}},{city:{$eq:req.cookies['city']}}]})